# Hide parts of window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I have an example url - http://localhost:4000/something&test@test.com&true

I need to hide everything after `http://localhost:4000/something`

I have the following code:

`var locationHref = window.location.href;
var splitLocationHref = locationHref.split('&')[0];`

Is it possible to just hide `&test@test.com&true` from the URL, without breaking the functionality that that part of the URL provides?

Comment: you probably need to look at routing, Try ui-router or similar

Answer (score 1):

No, the browser won't let you do this for security reasons. You'll need to change the page so that these values aren't passed in through the querystring